# Trigger is not working until i went to my path object

Tags: wpf, styles

I have a style for my path object this path is surrounded by a border when I'm writing a trigger that is not working until I went on to actual path object.

**Style**

```
<Style TargetType="Path">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource CloseButtonClr}"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="3"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource LableClr}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>



<Border Width="20" Grid.Column="2" Background="Transparent"  Margin="0,0,5,0" >
                        <Path  Data="M0,0 L1,1 M0,1 L1,0" />
                    </Border>
```

this is my code if I went on the path object then the trigger is working if went in between border and path object the trigger is not working, please help me wt I'm missing thanks

Comment: You're looking for ismouseover in a path. The path is unaware of any border. Why would it even decide to go look at the property of some other element?

Comment: There is no property `Border.IsMouseOver` as you seem to assume. `IsMouseOver` is a property declared by `UIElement` (the reason why it is permissible to write `Border.IsMouseOver` is because `Border` inherits from `UIElement`). Basically, writing `Border.IsMouseOver` is equivalent to writing `UIElement.IsMouseOver` or simply `IsMouseOver`. Thus, `Border.IsMouseOver` (or rather simply `IsMouseOver`) just refers to the IsMouseOver property of the Path element itself. That the WPF designer in Visual Studio lets you "fool" yourself like that is just a quirk of Visual Studio's designer ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `DataTrigger` to bind to the `IsMouseOver` property of the `Border`:

```
<Style TargetType="Path">
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource CloseButtonClr}"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="3"></Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource LableClr}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Border}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="{DynamicResource LableClr}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

A `Trigger` in a `Path` style can only bind to a property of the `Path` itself. The path `Border.IsMouseOver` will not bind to the parent `Border` element. It will bind to the `IsMouseOver` property of the `Path`. Both `Border` and `Path` inherit from `UIElement` where the property is actually defined.